# Passing hostname to netty

Tags: networking, apache-spark, netty

Background: I've got two machines with identical hostnames, I need to set up a local spark cluster for testing, setting up a master and a worker works fine, but trying to run an application with the driver causes problems, netty doesn't seem to be picking the correct host (regardless of what I put in there, it just picks the first host).

Identical hostname:

```
$ dig +short corehost
192.168.0.100
192.168.0.101
```

Spark config (used by master and the local worker):

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/some/dir
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=corehost       // i tried various like 192.168.0.x for
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=corehost      // local, master and the driver
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2g
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2
export SPARK_WORKER_DIR=/some/dir
```

Spark starts up and I can see the worker in the web-ui.
When I run the spark "job" below:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AaA")
                          // tried 192.168.0.x and localhost
                          .setMaster("spark://corehost:7077")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

I get this exception:

```
15/04/02 12:34:04 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.3.0
15/04/02 12:34:04 WARN Utils: Your hostname, corehost resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.0.100 instead (on interface en1)
15/04/02 12:34:04 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
15/04/02 12:34:05 ERROR NettyTransport: failed to bind to corehost.home/192.168.0.101:0, shutting down Netty transport
...
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Failed to bind to: corehost.home/192.168.0.101:0: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries!
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:393)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:389)
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
15/04/02 12:34:05 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
15/04/02 12:34:05 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
15/04/02 12:34:05 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Not sure how to proceed... its a whole jungle of ip addresses.
Not sure if this is a netty issue either.

Comment: dig only queries the DNS service; while hostname uses glibc's internal name resolution path, which also looks at the files that are present on the system such as `/etc/hosts`. This file probably has the mapping for `corehost` that netty is complaining about. You can check this mapping using `getent host corehost`.

Comment: @Petesh It's not a case of bad mapping, there are two physical machines with the same hostname on the same network. The problem is that without the additional settings that Lyuben mentioned in his answer the driver wasn't sure which of the two hosts to pick. Thanks for your idea though! Useful debugging tool.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with the identical problem is that it revolves around setting things up locally. Try being more verbose in your spark driver code, add the SPARK_LOCAL_IP and driver host ip to the config:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AaA")
                          .setMaster("spark://localhost:7077")
                          .set("spark.local.ip","192.168.1.100")
                          .set("spark.driver.host","192.168.1.100")
```

This should tell netty which of the two identical hosts to use.